# Retrieving information from DataKinds constrained existential types

Tags: haskell, existential-type, data-kinds

If I have a type constrained by a finite `DataKind`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

data K = A | B

data Ty (a :: K) = Ty { ... }
```

and an existential type which forgets the exact choice of `K` in the type... but remembers it in a passed dictionary.

```
class AK (t :: K) where k :: Ty t -> K
instance AK A where k _ = A
instance AK B where k _ = B

data ATy where ATy :: AK a => Ty a -> ATy
```

it's genuinely the case that `ATy <-> Either (Ty A) (Ty B)`, but if I want to write one of those witnesses I need to use `unsafeCoerce`

```
getATy :: ATy -> Either (Ty A) (Ty B)
getATy (ATy it) = case k it of
  A -> Left  (unsafeCoerce it)
  B -> Right (unsafeCoerce it)
```

---

So generally this works—I can forget the choice of `K` using `ATy` and remember it partially using `getATy`. Altogether this takes advantage of as much type information as I have available.

However, this type information feels as though it ought to be "obvious" if done correctly.

Is there a way to achieve the above without the use of `unsafeCoerce`? Is there a way to get rid of that `AK` constraint in the existential? Can this technique be performed based entirely off the information constraints provided by the data kind?

Comment: Ahm... `A -> Left Ty`?

Comment: Ah, uh, let me change the example to make it less trivial. Whoops!

Comment: The `K` type might be phantom, but it conveys a lot of information still.

Comment: the `AK` class doesn't compile with my GHC 7.8 because `k`'s type doesn't mention any class type variable.

Comment: Typo, sorry: `a -> t`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to do runtime case analysis on the existential type, you need a singleton representation too:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data K = A | B

-- runtime version of K. 
data SK (k :: K) where
    SA :: SK A
    SB :: SK B

-- ScopedTypeVariables makes it easy to specify which "k" we want. 
class AK (k :: K) where
    k :: SK k 

instance AK A where k = SA
instance AK B where k = SB

data Ty (a :: K) = Ty

data ATy where
    ATy :: AK k => Ty k -> ATy

getATy :: ATy -> Either (Ty A) (Ty B)
getATy (ATy (ty :: Ty k)) = case (k :: SK k) of
    SA -> Left ty
    SB -> Right ty
```

The `singletons` package can be used here to do away with the boilerplate:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, TypeFamilies, TemplateHaskell, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d| data K = A | B |])

data Ty (a :: K) = Ty

data ATy where
    ATy :: SingI k => Ty k -> ATy

getATy :: ATy -> Either (Ty A) (Ty B)
getATy (ATy (ty :: Ty k)) = case (sing :: Sing k) of
    SA -> Left ty
    SB -> Right ty
```

As to your last question:

> Is there a way to get rid of that AK constraint in the existential?
>   Can this technique be performed based entirely off the information
>   constraints provided by the data kind?

As long as we have a data kind only as a type parameter, the information doesn't exist runtime, and we can't do any analysis on it. For example, take this type:

```
data ATy where
    ATy :: Ty k -> ATy
```

we can never instantiate the `k` in `Ty k`; it must remain polymorphic.

There are multiple ways to provide runtime type information; implicitly passed dictionaries is one option, as we've seen:

```
data ATy where
   ATy :: AK k => Ty k -> ATy
```

Here `AK k` is just a pointer to an `SK` (since the `AK` class only has a single method, we don't have a dictionary for the class, just a plain pointer to the method), an extra field in the constructor. We could also choose to make that field explicit:

```
data ATy where
    ATy :: SK k -> Ty k -> ATy
```

and the runtime representation would be pretty much the same.

A third option would be using GADT constructors to encode the types:

```
data ATy where
    ATyA :: Ty A -> ATy
    ATyB :: Ty B -> ATy
```

This solution is pretty nice performance wise, since there is no space overhead, as the constructors already encode the types. It's like an `Either` with hidden type parameters.

Comment: Ah, so the singleton GADT carries around the type equality we need. That's the piece I was missing

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I added some notes on alternative type representations.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info. This is exactly what I was missing.