# DataKinds and type class instances

Tags: haskell, typeclass, data-kinds

The following example is a boiled-down version of my real-life problem. It seems to be in some way similar to [Retrieving information from DataKinds constrained existential types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387865/retreiving-information-from-datakinds-constrained-existential-types), but I could not quite get the answers I was seeking.

Suppose we have a finite, promoted DataKind `K` with types `A` and `B`, and a poly-kinded `Proxy` data-type to generate terms with types of kind *.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, GADTs, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}

data K = A | B

data Proxy :: k -> * where Proxy :: Proxy k
```

Now I want to write `Show`-instances for every type `Proxy a` where `a` is of kind `K`, which are exactly two:

```
instance Show (Proxy A) where show Proxy = "A"
instance Show (Proxy B) where show Proxy = "B"
```

But to use the `Show`-instance, I have to explicitly provide the context, even if the kind is restricted to `K`:

```
test :: Show (Proxy a) => Proxy (a :: K) -> String
test p = show p
```

My goal is to get rid of the type-class constraint. This may seem unimportant, but in my real application, this has major implications.

I could also define a single, but more general `Show`-instance like this:

```
instance Show (Proxy (a :: K)) where show p = "?"
```

This actually allows me to drop the constraint, but the new problem is to differentiate between the two types `A` and `B`.

So, is there a way to eat my cake and have it too? That is, not having to provide a type-class constraint in the type of `test` (kind annotations are fine, though), and still having two different `show` implementations (e.g. by differentiating the types somehow)?

Actually, it would also be okay to drop the entire type class, if I could simply associate the respective types (`A`, `B`) with their specific values (here: `"A"`, `"B"`) in a context where I just have the type information. I have no idea how to do this, though.

I would be very thankful for any provided insights.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible. In a context where you have "just the type information", at run-time, you really have *no* information. Type information is erased. So even for closed kinds, where it is in principle possible to show that given the type in question, you can always come up with a dictionary, you still need the class constraint. The class constraint ensures that at compile time, when GHC knows the type, it can select the appropriate instance to pass along. At run-time, the information which type it is is lost, and there's no chance to do the same. Writing a "one size fits all" instance does indeed work, because then the exact type does not matter for the choice anymore.

I don't know the full picture, but it may be possible to work around this by explicitly bundling up either the class dictionary or the string itself with the value you are passing around ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I feared that it wasn't possible. I guess I will have to find a work-around.

Answer (score 6):

You can add another class.

```
class Kish (k :: K) where
  toK :: proxy k -> K

instance Kish A where
  toK _ = A

instance Kish B where
  toK _ = B

instance Kish k => Show (Proxy k) where
  showsPrec n _ = case toK (Proxy :: Proxy k) of
    A -> ...
    B -> ...
```

Now you'll still be stuck with a context, but it's a more general one that might well be useful for other things too.

If it turns out that you tend to need to distinguish the proxies a lot, then you should switch to a GADT that you can just inspect as needed instead of using a proxy.

Comment: Something like this might prove to be useful, I will keep it in mind, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing that:

1. `a` is of kind `K`
2. the only types of kind `K` are `A` and `B`
3. `Show (Proxy A)` holds
4. `Show (Proxy B)` holds

is sufficient to prove that `Show (Proxy a)` holds. But a type class isn't just a proposition that we need to prove true to use with our type, it also provides implementations. To actually use `show (x :: Proxy a)` we need to not just prove that an implementation for `Show (Proxy a)` *exists*, we need to actually know which one it is.

Haskell type variables (without constraints) are parametric: there's no way to be fully polymorphic in `a`, and also be able to inspect `a` to provide different behaviour for `A` and `B`. The "different behaviour" you want is about as "close to parametric" as you can possibly be without actually being parametric, since it's just the selection of a different instance for each type when you know there is one for each type. But it's still something that breaks the contract of what `test :: forall (a :: K). Proxy a -> String` means.

Type class constraints allow your code to be non-parametric in the constrained type variables, in as much as you can use the type class' mapping from types to implementations to switch how your code behaves based on the type it's invoked at. So `test :: forall (a :: K). Show (Proxy a) => Proxy a -> String` works. (In terms of the actual implementation, the same ultimate caller who gets to choose the type `a` also provides the `Show (Proxy a)` instance for the code generated from your function to use).

You can use your `instance Show (Proxy (a :: K))` idea; now your function that *is* parametric in a type `a :: K` can still use `show (x :: Proxy a)` because there is one instance that works for all `a :: K`. But the instance itself runs into the same problem; the implementation of `show` in the instance is parametric in `a`, and so can't inspect it in anyway in order to return a different string based on the type.

You can use something like dfeuer's answer, where `Kish` exploits the non-parametricity of constrained type variables to basically allow you to inspect the type at runtime; the instance dictionary passed along to satisfy the `Kish a` constraint basically *is* a run time record of which type was chosen for the variable `a` (in a roundabout way). Pushing this idea further gets you all the way to `Typeable`. But you still need some sort of constraint to make your code non-parametric in `a`.

You can also use a type that is explicitly a runtime representation of the choice of `A` or `B` (as opposed to `Proxy`, which is an empty value at runtime and only provides a compile-time representation of the choice), something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, StandaloneDeriving #-}

data K = A | B

data KProxy (a :: K)
  where KA :: KProxy A
        KB :: KProxy B

deriving instance Show (KProxy a)

test :: KProxy a -> String
test = show
```

(Note here I can not only implement `Show (Kproxy a)`, I can actually derive it, although it does require standalone deriving)

This is using a GADT `KProxy` to allow `test` to be non-parametric in `a`, essentially doing the same job as the `Kish` constraint from dfeuer's answer but avoiding the need to add an extra constraint to your type signatures. In an earlier version of this post I stated that `test` was able to do this while remaining "just" parametric in `a`, which was incorrect.

Of course now to pass a proxy you have to actually write `KA` or `KB`. That's no bother where you were having to write `Proxy :: Proxy A` to actually choose the type (which is often the case with proxies, given that you usually only use them to fix a type that otherwise would be ambiguous). But where it would have been unambiguous anyway the compiler will catch you if you're inconsistent with the rest of the call, but you can't write just one symbol like `Proxy` and have the compiler infer the correct meaning. You can address *that* with a type class:

```
class KProxyable (a :: K)
  where kproxy :: KProxy a

instance KProxyable A
  where kproxy = KA

instance KProxyable B
  where kproxy = KB
```

Then you can use `KA` instead of `Proxy :: Proxy A`, and `kproxy` instead of letting the compiler infer the type of a bare `Proxy`. Stupid example time:

```
foo :: KProxy a -> KProxy a -> String
foo kx ky = show kx ++ " " ++ show ky
```

GHCI:

```
λ foo KA kproxy
"KA KA"
```

Note I'm not actually needing to have a `KProxyable` constraint anywhere; I use `kproxy` at a point where the type *is* known. This still has to "come in from the top", though (exactly as the instance dictionary satisfying your `Show (Proxy a)` constraint would); there's no way to have a function parametric in a type `a :: K` come up with the relevant `KProxy a` on its own.

Because it's the correspondence between the constructors and the type that makes this work, I don't believe you can make a generic proxy in this style the way you can with the empty-at-runtime `Proxy`. TemplateHaskell could certainly generate such proxy types for you though; I think the concept of *singletons* is the general idea here, and so the https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons probably provides what you need, but I'm not very familiar with how to actually use that package.

Comment: Couldn't `foo` learn `a` by pattern matching? Such information generally becomes available on the RHS of a GADT pattern match. Also, `KProxy` is probably a poor name since it's used in `Data.Proxy`.

Comment: @dfeuer You're quite right, `foo` can learn the type of `ky` by pattern matching on `kx`... so GADTs break parametricity?

Comment: @dfeuer I suppose of course they do, that's a lot of the point. \*sounds of mental models updating\*

Comment: This is why Agda, as I understand it, distinguishes between a "parameter" and an "index". This also relates to GHC's somewhat messy/limited "type role" mechanism.