# Typeclass instantiated on every value of a data kind

Tags: haskell, typeclass, data-kinds

Is it possible to specify that every member of a datakind satisfies a typeclass, such that the class constraint is implied?  E.g.

```
data AB = A | B
class Foo (a :: AB) where get :: proxy a -> String
instance Foo A where get _ = "A"
instance Foo B where get _ = "B"

-- note lack of constraint here
get' :: proxy (a :: AB) -> String
get' = get
```

Basically `a` is an `AB` so we're sure there's an instance of `Foo` for it.
I find it unlikely -- where is it going to get the `Foo` dictionary? -- but I've seen some magic in my day.

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408110/datakinds-and-type-class-instances but reopened it. The separate `Foo` class constrained to only operate on `AB` might leave room for magic I can't imagine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The primary problem is that, as you mention, there's nothing there to get you a dictionary. But the other problem is that your claim that every type in `AB` is an instance of `Foo` is false.

```
type family Broken :: AB where
```

Comment: Or `GHC.Exts.Any :: AB`.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't considered that all kinds might have a "bottom", which would certainly put a damper on things semantically.  Then it makes sense to constrain to normal-form kinds, perhaps with a class `NF k`, which could then be used to provide the necessary dictionaries.  Hmmm....   anyway, thanks for the insight

Comment: @luqui, a singleton will do. `data ABy x where Ay :: ABy 'A; By :: ABy 'B`. If you like, `class KnownAB x where knownAB :: ABy x`. Pattern matching on `knownAB` lets you use the instances.

Comment: @luqui, you can use a singleton like **dfeuer** suggested, but also get rid of explicit pattern matching like [this](http://lpaste.net/349915).

Comment: More on stuck type families [on Richard Eisenberg's blog](https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2015/09/09/what-are-type-families/)